# Is there a way to reduce the size of the Git folder?

Tags: git

It seems like my project is getting bigger and bigger with every Git `commit/push`. Is there a way to clean up my Git folder?

Comment: Related: *[Make Git consume less disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398919/)* and *[Reduce Git repository size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116778/reduce-git-repository-size/2116892#2116892)*

Answer (score 238, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want. First of all, of course each time you commit/push the directory is going to get a little larger, since it has to store each of those additional commits.

However, probably you want `git gc` which will "cleanup unnecessary files and optimize the local repository" ([manual page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc)).

Another possibly relevant command is `git clean` which will **delete** untracked files from your tree ([manual page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean)).

Comment: git clean -d -f -x deletes files listed in .gitignore and such. E.g. workspaces that don't belong in git, Pods folder, etc.

Comment: **`WARNING`** The command as written above by @Kalle will remove **EVERY _>UNTRACKED< FILE AND DIRECTORY_ WITHIN YOUR GIT ROOT**, _not_ just "files listed in .gitignore". Anything that is not being tracked by Git, regardless of whether or not it is listed in `.gitignore` will be wiped. `git clean -dfX` (note the case on the `X`) will only remove items which have an applicable rule in `.gitignore`. **Please heed this warning:** _Never run `git clean` without either running it in interactive mode, with `-i` instead of `-f`, or at least doing a dry run first — `-n` and then again with `-f`._

Comment: Or making a backup :-)

Comment: And making a backup

Answer (score 75):

Run:

```
git remote prune origin
```

It deletes all stale tracking branches which have already been removed at `origin`, but which are still locally available in `remotes/origin`.

```
git gc --auto
```

'**G** arbage **C** ollection' - runs housekeeping tasks (compresses revisions, and removes loose/inaccessible objects). The `--auto` flag first determines whether any work is required, and exits without doing anything if not.

Comment: Some explanation of what those do? I know that we can Google them and search for their documentation, but it is a common practice to provide short description of your answer when it involves just code or commands.

Answer (score 28):

One scenario where your git repo will get *seriously* bigger with each commit is one where you are committing binary files that you generate regularly. [Their storage won't be as efficient than text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266737/git-style-backup-of-binary-files/2266961#2266961).

Another is one where you have a huge number of files within *one* repo (which is a [limit of git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984707/what-are-the-git-limits/984973#984973)) instead of several subrepos ([managed as submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899373/transferring-legacy-code-base-from-cvs-to-distributed-repository-e-g-git-or-mer/899428#899428)).

In this [article on git space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869213/how-does-git-save-space-and-is-fast-at-the-same-time/2869354#2869354), AlBlue mentions:

> Note that Git (and Hg, and other DVCSs) do suffer from a problem where (large) binaries are checked in, then deleted, as they'll still show up in the repository and take up space, even if they're not current.

If you have large binaries stored in your git repo, you may consider:

- managing those binaries in [an external repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037664/does-any-version-control-system-like-svn-git-or-mercurial-let-you-keep-latest/3038857#3038857).
- [manage your .git repo size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925884/managing-git-file-size/2926604#2926604)
- try and remove those binaries from your history [with `git filter-branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904860/how-to-remove-unreferenced-blobs-from-my-git-repo/1908476#1908476) (warning: this will rewrite the history, which is bad if you have already pushed your repo and if other have pulled from it)

As I mentioned in "[What are the file limits in Git (number and size)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/984973/6309)", the more recent (2015, 5 years after this answer) [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) from GitHub is a way to manage those large files (by storing them *outside* the Git repository).

Comment: git large file support is helpful if you have large binary files (like images) routinely being added / updated. See https://git-lfs.github.com/. Super easy to implement, supported by github. All team members need to install it to make use of it collaboratively.

Comment: @EricWoods True. I mentioned Git-LFS before (64 times: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a6309%20git-lfs). I have edited this old answer accordingly.

Comment: Ha, indeed! Funny how a 9+ year old answer is still relevant (and now even more so with the LFS info).

Answer (score 28):

Yes, yes, `git gc` is the solution, naturally.

And locally, you can just delete the local repository and clone it again

#### But there is something more important here...

The seconds you wait for that huge Git and externals to process are collected to long minutes in which are collected to hours of inefficient time spent.

**Create a new *(entirely, not just a branch)* repository from scratch**, including the only recent version of files, *naturally* you'll lose all the history.

But when in the code world, it is not time to get sentimental. There isn't any point in dragging along the entire 5 years of code for every commit or diff.
You can still store the old Git and externals somewhere, if you get nostalgic :]

But, at some point you really have to move along :]

Your team will thank you!

Comment: Completely agree, we recently took this approach with an old repository and haven't looked back; well, mainly because we can't, but you know what I mean :)

Answer (score 20):

Running this command is extremely dangerous, but it will shrink your repository by erasing all your Git recovery/backup files:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

It will erase all files Git uses to recover your repository from some bad command. For example, if you did `git reset --hard`, you can usually recover the files lost. But if you do `git reset --hard` before the `git reflog expire...` command, then you lost everything. Now, your only hope is to use some tool which analyses your file system and try to recover the erased files, if they were not overridden.

Comment: I really wouldn’t call this *extremely dangerous*. I’d just label it something you have to be *careful* with. In my experience, very few indeed ever touch the reflog or unreachable objects—most don’t even know they’re there or how to interact with them, and so get stuck in situations where they’d be useful, or do things a terribly inefficient way. I’d go so far as to say that if you don’t know and can’t figure out what these commands will do, then you can safely run them!

Answer (score 12):

`git clean -d -f -i` is the best way to  do it.

This will help to clean in a more  controlled manner.

`-i` stands for interactive.

Comment: While the OP's question is vague, and this is a good answer in that respect, I do want to point out that `git clean` is not for cleaning up the repo so much as cleaning up the directory. For users who blindly copy/paste, beware; this removes untracked files/dirs you might actually want locally.

Comment: git clean -d -x -f works nicely if you want to deep clean

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will shrink it, but after I run `git clean`, I often do `git repack -ad` as well, which reduces the number of pack files.

Comment: repack is a part of `git gc` process, so no need to run it separately