# What kind of code can I use GitHub for?

Tags: github, svn, version-control, svn-checkout

What kind of code (what coding languages) can I use GitHub for? Can I use it for websites? Flash? Can I upload images files and other resources?

(I am completely unfamiliar with Git and SVN.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On git, svn and mercurial:**

git, svn, Mercurial are all version control systems. svn was a great improvement over cvs, a commonly used version control system prior to emergence of new VCS. svn like cvs has a client-server model. git and mercurial provides a distributed version control system that does not depend on network as any repository is self contained with all the history and change records. Of course, there are other goodies.

Remember that version control system solves the problem of "the cat ate my code". You can use it to track any kind of development - code, text documents etc.

**On github, bitbucket, code.google.com and codplex:**

These provide additional goodies on top of what a version control system provides.

1. They provide you storage for keeping your repository, which you can access and share with the world.
2. When you share code, you would want to also provide documentation. They provide wiki support for this purpose.
3. They also provide ticketing / bug management system which can ease a development project.

In short, they provide various tools that can help in project management and development of your code.

Since you are getting to whet the knowledge in some of these areas,  following links will be a very useful introductions:

1. [**a-visual-guide-to-version-control**](http://betterexplained.com/articles/a-visual-guide-to-version-control/)
2. [**intro-to-distributed-version-control-illustrated**](http://betterexplained.com/articles/intro-to-distributed-version-control-illustrated/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use GitHub for any source code you want to manage.

But you actually can also [use GitHub for your blog(!)](https://github.com/blog/164-use-github-as-your-blog), the idea being that you would manage your articles and their revisions as you would for a source code base.
(Example: [git-blog](https://github.com/elliottcable/git-blog))

More general documentations: [GitHub features](https://github.com/features/projects) (wiki, issue tracking, code review...).

Comment: Don't commit too much binaries though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119850/is-there-a-way-to-clean-up-git/3120006#3120006

Answer (score 0):

Git does not restrict the kind of files you can track with it... use Github for anything your project needs to track!

Check out http://help.github.com/ for some documentation on how to get started using Git in conjunction with GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Version control can be applied to ANY file type. From text to images to Flash to whatever. Subversion is my Version control system of choice, and I host my own Subversion server.

As for Git. Well Git is just another version control system. Again, the same rules apply, you can version any file-type. Git-Hub is a public Git server that you can register for and use. You can make your repository public or private.

You cannot however host a site on git-hub. You can do rudimentary blogs, and use the git-feeds to feed your site, but you can't really use it as a traditional web site.