# Difference between Git and Nexus?

Tags: git, repository, nexus

I can't seem to find what the difference is between Git and [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/). Are the two comparable?

Comment: Source code in Git, build output in Nexus.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There are both referential:

- one ([Git](http://git-scm.com/)) is a source referential for version control (with features like merging, branching, tags)
- the other ([Nexus](http://www.sonatype.com/)) is an artifact referential for any delivery (binaries or not)

The referential database differs also:

- Git has its own internal repository storage mechanism
- Nexus is simply a collection of shared directories with a naming convention ( group.artifact.version ).
  As described in "[What is a repository](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/repoman-sect-repo.html)": a collection of binary software artifacts and metadata stored in a defined directory structure.

The idea is that, for large deliveries that can be produced quite often, it is much easier to store them in Nexus ( you can clean them easily enough: `cd` + `rm` ), as opposed to version them ( which makes a DVCS repo like Git way too big way too fast to be cloned easily ).

So their goals are different, as I explain in:

- "[How do different version control systems handle binary files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598700/how-do-different-version-control-systems-handle-binary-files/6599303#6599303)"
- "[Best practice to store .jar files in VCS (SVN, Git, …)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329041/best-practice-to-store-jar-files-in-vcs-svn-git/3329272#3329272)"
- "[Using source controlled libraries in source controlled projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171267/using-source-controlled-libraries-in-source-controlled-projects/3171360#3171360)"

You manage what you *code* in Git, and what you *build* in Nexus.

Answer (score 35):

@VonC has the high level, theoretical view.

In everyday use, you'd store your source code and its history in a git repository, and store your build artifacts (e.g. the compiled software you want to deliver) in Nexus.

As such, they are not really comparable, but complementary.